# Dynamic Div-Tabs & Content in PHP

Tags: php, tabs

I have searched for this before but haven't found anything specific that addresses my problem:

I am generating Div-Tabs dynamically by fetching data from database (PHP & SQL). Let's say these Div-Tabs are a summaries of Profiles and the relevant content has detailed information about these Profiles. Now, I managed to get the Div-Tabs to show dynamically and that's working 100% fine. However, I am unable to 'Wrap' the Div-Tab-Content for a specific Tab. In other words, if there are 5 Tabs lined up beautifully, as they should, I also have all content of all the 5 Tabs lined up one below the other. Clicking on a specific Tab does nothing.

The Tabs are being called via a While-Loop. So I'm inserting an Id successfully, but these very same Ids are also looping in the Div-Content space and showing up all content for every Tab.

This is what I've used (it's of course a skimmed-down version:

```
<!-- DIV TABS --> 
<div>
    <ul>
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['subEmail'])) {
        $proUser = $_SESSION['subEmail'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE proUser = '$proUser'";
        $selectProfile = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
        $i = 0; //counter for active
        $active = 'active';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($selectProfile)) {
                $proId = $row['proId'];
                $proFirstName = $row['firstName'];
                $proImage = $row['proImage'];

            if ($i == 1) { $active = ''; }

                echo "<li class='glide__slide nav-item'>
                        <a class='card nav-link $active' id='$proId' data-toggle='tab' href='#$proId' role='tab'>
                            <div class='card-body text-center'>
                                <img src='img/profiles/$proImage' alt='$proFirstName' class='img-thumbnail border-0 rounded-circle list-thumbnail align-self-center small'/>
                                <p class='list-item-heading pt-3 mb-2 truncate'>$proFirstName</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>";
                $i++;
            }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
                    
<!-- TAB CONTENT -->
<div class="tab-content mt-3">
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['subEmail'])) {
$proUser = $_SESSION['subEmail'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE proUser = '$proUser'";
$selectProfile = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($selectProfile)) {
        $proId = $row['proId'];
        $proFirstName = $row['firstName'];
        $proImage = $row['proImage'];
?> 
<!-- TAB PANEL -->
<div class="tab-pane show active" id="<?php echo $proId; ?>" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mb-1">
        <div class="card d-flex flex-row mb-1">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <div class="min-width-zero">
                   <img src="img/profiles/<?php echo $proImage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $proFirstName ?>"
                        class="img-thumbnail border-0 rounded-circle list-thumbnail align-self-center large" />
                        <p class="card-text pt-2 mb-0"><?php echo $proName; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
<?php }} ?>
```

I would appreciate it if someone can show me a simple demo of how to get this working because I'm very new to PHP and am still learning. (So please be patient and gentle with your opinions/comments/criticisms).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you loop through both divs ? can you add that code as well ?

Comment: Updated the code to show what I've used for the Tab & Content. Tabs are working fine, but content of all Tabs show up one below the other.

Comment: Does `href='#$proId' ` showing right value ? Check in your browser elements tabs and see generated htmls .Also ,your all tabs content will have `active` class according to your code isn't only one should have that ?

Comment: Strangely enough, no - all Tabs do not become 'Active'. I removed the Active element in the div tabs, but still content from all tabs show up together. I'm quite certain it's to do with the loop, but can't understand what the issue is.

Comment: No, its because of `show` class which you have added on every divs content remove them .Also you have use same id on `a` tag and div content as well.. remove that `id='$proId'` from `a` tag because here `href="#$proId"` will call your tabs when you click on it.